# Metadata Cleanup Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, metadata

I have 2x Windows Server 2008, and 1x Windows Server 2003 that doesn't boot any more. I need to remove the 2003 server from the DC role.

I found this [Microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816907%28WS.10%29.aspx). It says that you can remove a DC just by removing it from ADUC and it'll do the Metadata removable automatically.

I have two questions:

1. I've never 100% trusted Microsoft documents at face value. Has anyone done this and not have to go back to clean any metadata up?
2. The document doesn't list what functional level is required. I'm assuming it's just dependent on the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article seems to imply what you're implying, based on this paragraph:

*As long as you are using the Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, or RSAT versions of Dsa.msc or Dssite.msc, you can clean up metadata automatically for domain controllers running earlier versions of Windows operating systems.*